# SQlite select statement

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor, android-arrayadapter

I have a sqlite statement but it gives me error in where clause and the function "sres.getsrthreadid" in where clause is returning me the mac address with some number at last. My function is:

```
SResponses sres=new SResponses();
String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_POSITION + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+ "="+sres.getsrthreadid();

Log.e("datasource", sres.getsrthreadid());
cursors = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
```

Logcat is:

```
11-07 11:50:35.721: E/datasource(14881): b8:b4:2e:36:6c:6c1
11-07 11:50:35.721: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(14881): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ":b4": syntax error, db=/data/data/soft.b.peopleassist/databases/sentitems.db
11-07 11:50:35.722: D/AndroidRuntime(14881): Shutting down VM
11-07 11:50:35.722: W/dalvikvm(14881): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e42258)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.SResponses}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":b4": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT id,message,threadid,position FROM message WHERE threadid=b8:b4:2e:36:6c:6c1
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1251)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":b4": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT id,message,threadid,position FROM message WHERE threadid=b8:b4:2e:36:6c:6c1
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:177)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:395)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1538)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at soft.b.peopleassist.DataSource.getAllMessages(DataSource.java:173)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at soft.b.peopleassist.SResponses.onCreate(SResponses.java:40)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4510)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2048)
11-07 11:50:35.731: E/AndroidRuntime(14881):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote your input value so that SQLite can get it correctly:

```
String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+","
+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_POSITION + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+ "='"+sres.getsrthreadid() + "'; // Here
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your code with this

```
SResponses sres=new SResponses();
String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_POSITION + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+ "='" + sres.getsrthreadid() + "'";

Log.e("datasource", sres.getsrthreadid());
cursors = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
```